# Nodemailer is not checking the specified viewPath

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer, express-handlebars

I am trying to send an HTML email using Nodemailer and nodemailer-express-handlebars.
So I created an HTML template and place it under "templates" folder (see below image) and specified its path in my code so that Nodemailer can go and get the template.

However, Nodemailer is checking the path different from the one I specified.

Project structure:

[image]

## What I tried and what I want to ask

I tested the behavior in pattern 1 and 2 as shown below.
Pattern 1 is the problematic case for me.

**In pattern1, how can I make Nodemailer check the viewPath which I specified?**

## Pattern 1: Not working as expected

The `viewPath` is "/home/honda/develoment/phaser_projects/test/templates".
I expect nodemailer to check this path for the template file.

```js
const hbs = require("nodemailer-express-handlebars");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const emailProvider = process.env.EMAIL_PROVIDER;
const emailFrom = process.env.EMAIL_FROM;
const emailTo = process.env.EMAIL_TO;
const pass = process.env.PASSWORD;

const smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: emailProvider,
  auth: {
    user: emailFrom,
    pass: pass
  }
});

// Specify the viewPath here
const handlebarsOptions = {
  viewEngine: "handlebars",
  viewPath: "/home/honda/develoment/phaser_projects/test/templates",
  extName: ".html"
};

smtpTransport.use("compile", hbs(handlebarsOptions));

const data = {
  to: emailTo,
  from: emailFrom,
  template: "test-template",
  subject: "Test Subject",
};

smtpTransport.sendMail(data)
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Then I got the below error message.
Nodemailer is checking the path "/home/honda/develoment/phaser_projects/test/main.handlebars".

**My expectation:

Nodemailer check the path "/home/honda/develoment/phaser_projects/test/templates", which I specified.**

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/honda/develoment/phaser_projects/test/main.handlebars'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/home/honda/develoment/phaser_projects/test/main.handlebars'
}
```

## Pattern 2: Working as expected

The `viewPath` is replaced with "/home/honda/develoment/phaser_projects/test/**templatessss**".
This is a wrong path because the directory "**templatessss**" does not exist.

```js
const handlebarsOptions = {
  viewEngine: "handlebars",
  viewPath: "/home/honda/develoment/phaser_projects/test/templatessss", // templatessss does not exist
  extName: ".html"
};
```

Then I got the below error message.
In this case, Nodemailer obviously didn't find the template because the path does not exist, but anyway **it checked the path I specified**, which is expected behavior.

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/honda/develoment/phaser_projects/test/templatessss/test-template.html'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/home/honda/develoment/phaser_projects/test/templatessss/test-template.html'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem and after suffering decided to change `defaultLayout` to `false` and this helped me. Maybe it could help you too.

```
const templatesPath = path.join(__dirname, 'templates');

transporter.use(
  'compile',
  hbs({
    viewEngine: {
      extname: '.handlebars',
      defaultLayout: false
    },
    viewPath: templatesPath,
    extName: '.handlebars'
  })
);
```